# Firefox Addon Development - Usage of low-level or non-SDK interface

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am working on Firefox Addon development, I have successfully built the addon, but it is giving me validation error on submission as "Warning: Your add-on uses an interface which bypasses the high-level protections of the add-on SDK. This interface should be avoided, and its use may significantly complicate your review process." on these lines.

```
const { Cc, Ci } = require("chrome"),
nsIIOService = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIOService),
nsIStyleSheetService = Cc["@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIStyleSheetService);
```

I am able run the addon on my machine, but couldn't submit due to this flagged validation check.

Is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 0):

It is completely acceptable to use that. There is not alternative to some APIs in the SDK. That validation is a warning because those features are not frozen and can change at anytime. Can you post a screenshot of the validation blocking your submission? It should be allowed through.

Comment: Though it is allowed, my addon wont be granted a full review!

Comment: That's real odd. Can you please share a screenshot, or the email message the reviewer shared with you. Did a reviewer reject your addon?

Comment: Addon was preliminary reviewed. Reviewer's comment - 1) Add-on must unregister/disconnect observers, remove listeners, clearInterval (for setInterval), revert all built-in preferences which add-on changes, and remove its own imported modules (not imported Firefox modules), unregisterSheet; on 'disable' or 'uninstall'.

Answer (score 0):

While not entirely identical in function to nsIStyleSheetService, sdk addons can use [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod(options)) to inject stylesheets into some or all content pages.